# How to install and run jmeter on raspbian (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: unix, jmeter, raspbian

i'm totally new to the whole Unix environment and trying to figure things out. I just setup my Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian OS. How do i : First, properly install JMeter. Second, run JMeter GUI?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you know about https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To install JMeter:

- Install [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Download JMeter from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
- Untar it using :

> tar xvf apache-jmeter-3.3.tgz

- Set path to java :

> export PATH=PATH_TO_JAVA:$PATH

- run jmeter from jmeter/bin folder:

> jmeter